# php foreach function inside another foreach function

Tags: php, function, foreach

```
<?php
        echo'<table border="1">';
        foreach (RetrieveSpecificSubMenu() as $value){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td colspan="2">';
            echo "Sub Menu Details";
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Sub Menu ID:";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
            echo "<input readonly type='text' name='submenuid' value=" .$value['menuid']. " class='box required'/>";
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Sub Menu Name:";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
            echo "<input type='text' name='submenuname' value='" .htmlspecialchars($value['menuname'], ENT_QUOTES). "' class='box required'/>";
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Parent Name:";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
            echo "<input type='text' name='parentid' value='" .htmlspecialchars($value['parentid'], ENT_QUOTES). "' class='box required'/>";
            echo'<select name="submenuurl">';
                    echo"<option value='" .htmlspecialchars($value['parentid'], ENT_QUOTES). "'>".$value['menuurl']."</option>";
                    foreach (RetrieveAllMenuinDatabase() as $value){
                        echo "<option value='".$value['menuname']."'>".$value['menuname']."</option>";
                    }   
        echo'</select>';
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Sub Menu Description:";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
            echo "<input type='text' name='submenudescription' value='" .htmlspecialchars($value['menudescription'], ENT_QUOTES). "' class='box required'/>";
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Sub Menu(Second Level):";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
                if($value['menuflag']==="1"){
                    echo "<input id='remember' class='submenumanagementmenuflag' type='checkbox' name='submenuflag' value='" .$value['menuflag']. "' class='box required' checked='checked'/>"."Yes";
                }else{
                    echo "<input id='remember' class='submenumanagementmenuflag' type='checkbox' name='submenuflag' value='" .$value['menuflag']. "' class='box required' check''/>"."Yes";
                }
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Display Order:";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
            echo "<input  type='text' name='submenudisplayorder' value=" .$value['menudisplayorder']. " class='box required'/>";
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "<tr class='submenumanagementurl'>";
            echo'<td>';
            echo "Menu Url:";
            echo'</td>';
            echo'<td>';
                echo'<select name="submenuurl">';
                    echo"<option value=" .$value['menuurl']. ">".$value['menuurl']."</option>";
                    foreach (RetrieveAllPages() as $value){
                        echo "<option value='".$value['Filename']."'>".$value['Filename']."</option>";
                    }   
        echo'</select>';
            echo'</td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        }   
        echo'</table>';
    ?>
```

This is working code of mind it gets data from database and shows them sa echo i had an idea to put another function inside which is the

`foreach (RetrieveAllMenuinDatabase() as $value){
echo "<option value='".$value['menuname']."'>".$value['menuname']."</option>";
}`

after putting this in code the rest of the value are not found why is this happening i just want to know why so i can find idea how to fix it.. any suggestion is appreciated

FYI the output for the inner `foreach` is the problem is the value that follows the `foreach` are all gone it gets error it says it is undefined

Comment: You keep overwriting your `$value` variable, is that intended?

Comment: so you mean to say i just need to rename it to different not $value?i see i didnt try it yet will try it now

Comment: it did work..i thought it would not matter thanks for the idea

Comment: And make sure you do not `echo` again and again ... you could concatenate the string

Comment: @Umair concatenate which string sir i would like to know what you are suggesting maybe it is better than what i have now.

Comment: Concatenate as I have posted in my answer... You can see my answer ... thats what I am suggesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you flirting with PHP?

Try out this code...

```
<?php

echo'<table border="1">';
foreach (RetrieveSpecificSubMenu() as $value) {
    echo "<tr>"
    . '<td colspan="2">'
    . "Sub Menu Details"
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Sub Menu ID:"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . "<input readonly type='text' name='submenuid' value=" . $value['menuid'] . " class='box required'/>"
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Sub Menu Name:"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . "<input type='text' name='submenuname' value='" . htmlspecialchars($value['menuname'], ENT_QUOTES) . "' class='box required'/>"
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Parent Name:"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . "<input type='text' name='parentid' value='" . htmlspecialchars($value['parentid'], ENT_QUOTES) . "' class='box required'/>"
    . '<select name="submenuurl">'
    . "<option value='" . htmlspecialchars($value['parentid'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'>" . $value['menuurl'] . "</option>";
            foreach (RetrieveAllMenuinDatabase() as $AllMenu) {
                echo "<option value='" . $AllMenu['menuname'] . "'>" . $AllMenu['menuname'] . "</option>";
            }
    echo '</select>'
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Sub Menu Description:"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . "<input type='text' name='submenudescription' value='" . htmlspecialchars($value['menudescription'], ENT_QUOTES) . "' class='box required'/>"
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Sub Menu(Second Level):"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>';
    if ($value['menuflag'] === "1") {
        echo "<input id='remember' class='submenumanagementmenuflag' type='checkbox' name='submenuflag' value='" . $value['menuflag'] . "' class='box required' checked='checked'/>" . "Yes";
    } else {
        echo "<input id='remember' class='submenumanagementmenuflag' type='checkbox' name='submenuflag' value='" . $value['menuflag'] . "' class='box required' check''/>" . "Yes";
    }
    echo '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Display Order:"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . "<input  type='text' name='submenudisplayorder' value=" . $value['menudisplayorder'] . " class='box required'/>"
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>"
    . "<tr class='submenumanagementurl'>"
    . '<td>'
    . "Menu Url:"
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . '<select name="submenuurl">'
    . "<option value=" . $value['menuurl'] . ">" . $value['menuurl'] . "</option>";
    foreach (RetrieveAllPages() as $AllPages) {
        echo "<option value='" . $AllPages['Filename'] . "'>" . $AllPages['Filename'] . "</option>";
    }
    echo'</select>'
    . '</td>'
    . "</tr>";
}
echo'</table>';
?>
```

Comment: i already know the solution thanks to the comment of Matteo Tassinari but for refrerence this is the answer some might need it

Answer (score 0):

In your inner foreach look you are overwriting the `$value` variable from the outer foreach :)